# Android MPchart get Y-Position of view after scrolling

Tags: java, android, scroll, mpandroidchart, yaxis

I use MPChart to plot rapidly updating data live. It is crucial that the user can freely scroll along the Y-Axis as the graph gets updated. After every update, I use `myChart.moveViewToX()` to automatically scroll along the x-axis. However, `moveViewToX()` also moves the view to 0 along the Y-axis.

Since `moveViewToX`does not feature a parameter like "ignoreY" or "keepY", I would like to use
`mChart.moveViewTo(centerX, centerY, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);`, where  `centerY` is the Y-Position that the user has scrolled to.

So far, I have not found any way to access this value in the MPChart documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the center Y by doing the following:

```
MPPointF centerPointPx = mChart.getViewPortHandler().getContentCenter();
MPPointD centerPointValue = mChart.getValuesByTouchPoint(centerPointPx.x, centerPointPx.y, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
```